# Camel RabbitMQ endpoint cannot be created when a dead letter exchange is declared

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, rabbitmq

I'm having an issue creating a RabbitMQ endpoint with Camel. The issue only occurs when I declare a a dead message letter exchange option based on the [camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html). This is my URN for creating the endpoint:

```
rabbitmq://localhost/com.mydomain.inbound.exhange?deadLetterExchange=dead.msgs
```

All is fine when I omit the deadLetterExchange option but as soon as I include it I get the following (not very helpful) exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.validateQueueNameLength(ChannelN.java:1244) ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:843) ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:61) ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQDeclareSupport.declareAndBindQueue(RabbitMQDeclareSupport.java:96) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQDeclareSupport.declareAndBindDeadLetterExchangeWithQueue(RabbitMQDeclareSupport.java:43) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQDeclareSupport.declareAndBindExchangesAndQueuesUsing(RabbitMQDeclareSupport.java:35) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint.declareExchangeAndQueue(RabbitMQEndpoint.java:222) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer.openChannel(RabbitConsumer.java:288) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer.(RabbitConsumer.java:57) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.createConsumer(RabbitMQConsumer.java:108) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.startConsumers(RabbitMQConsumer.java:90) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.doStart(RabbitMQConsumer.java:160) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3269) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3563) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers
>   ....

Just no note that I've also tried creating the exchange and queue manually in a hope that this may work but no luck.

Additional Info:

- camel-spring-boot-starter (2.17.0)
- camel-rabbitmq (2.17.0)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `deadLetterQueue`option -

`rabbitmq://localhost/com.mydomain.inbound.exhange?deadLetterExchange=dead.msgs&deadLetterQueue=my.dead.letter.queue`

I also had to add further options to the uri to get it to work. I added

- deadLetterExchangeType
- queueArgsConfigurer

The queueArgsConfigurer is an implementation of `org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.ArgsConfigurer`

```
class MyQueueArgs implements ArgsConfigurer {

    void configurArgs(Map<String, Object> args) { //misspelling!!
        args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "my.dead.letter")
        args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "my.dead.letter.key")
    }

}
```

Mine is a Spring app so `myArgs` (see below) is created in the bean factory.

So, the full uri is like this -

`rabbitmq://hostname/exchangeName?routingKey=$routingKey&vhost=virtualHostname&exchangeType=exType&autoDelete=false&queue=my.queue&deadLetterExchange=my.dead.letter&deadLetterExchangeType=dlExType&deadLetterQueue=my.dead.letter.queue&queueArgsConfigurer=#myArgs`

I probably don't need to specify the dead letter exchange in the uri and the ArgsConfigurer implementation.

For more on ArgsConfigurer this Camel issue might help - [#8457](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8487)

I had to look at the source code to figure a lot of this out. What is missing from the doc is a definition of dependencies. There are some options, particularly around dead letter exchanges, which become mandatory if another is specified. That's why you are getting your errors. Have a look at `populateQueueArgumentsFromDeadLetterExchange` in [RabbitMQDeclareSupport](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQDeclareSupport.java).

**EDIT**

A simplification to my answer - I dropped the `ArgsConfigurer` implementation in the end. I went with this -

`rabbitmq://myHostname/myExchangeName?
                username=myUserName&
                password=myPassword&
                queue=myQueueName&
                routingKey=myRoutingKey&
                vhost=myVirtualHostname&
                exchangeType=topic&
                autoDelete=false&
                deadLetterExchange=myDeadLetter&
                deadLetterExchangeType=topic&
                deadLetterQueue=myDeadLetterQueue&
                deadLetterRoutingKey=myDeadLetterRoutingKey&
                autoAck=false`

Comment: In trying this I get a new error at runtime: "**invalid arg 'x-dead-letter-routing-key**' for queue"... I'm interested to know why you believe this would work, the documentation does not indicate that **deadLetterQueue** is an option, is it undocumented?

Comment: I've extended my answer above

Comment: This worked for me.  It should be incorporated into the documentation

Comment: It shows up in the git repo but not in the actual documentation :(
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/8a1549fe64c6302f6b863dead2e701807072308a/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/docs/rabbitmq-component.adoc